# How to Use ViewPager Button On MainActivity Page?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager

How can I use Viewpager Adapter Button into MainActivity? I am developing a quiz app and I am comparing button value into MainActivity. How can I access ViewPagerAdapter class buttons In MainActivity?

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Ref.child("Exam_Category").child("PRACTICE TEST").child("PREVIOUS YEAR PAPER'S").child(ct1).child(ct2).child("ENGLISH COMPREHENSION").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        key = data.getKey().toString();


                        Ref.child("Exam_Category").child("PRACTICE TEST").child("PREVIOUS YEAR PAPER'S").child(ct1).child(ct2).child("ENGLISH COMPREHENSION").child(String.valueOf(key))
                                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                            final questions studentDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(questions.class);
                                            list.add(studentDetails);

                                            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Previous_Yr_Quiz.this, list);

                                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        }
                                    }


                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                    }
            }

                //total_q.setText(Question_No +" / "+key);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This is My ViewPager Adapter

```
public  class RecyclerViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public List<questions> list;




    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<questions> TempList) {
        this.context = context;

        this.list = TempList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public  Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView question;
        final Button option1,option2,option3,option4;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_layout_listview, container,
                false);



        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        question = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        option1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optiona);
        option2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionb);
        option3 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionc);
        option4 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optiond);





        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        questions studentDetails = list.get(position);
        question.setText(studentDetails.getQuestion());
        option1.setText(studentDetails.getOption1());
        option1.setId(position);
        option2.setText(studentDetails.getOption2());
        option3.setText(studentDetails.getOption3());
        option4.setText(studentDetails.getOption4());



        option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                option1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong);

            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;


    }






    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);



    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return list.size();

    }



}
```

How can used button options A, B, C, D OnClick in MainActivity because I compare button value into A, B, C, D buttons....

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Make Buttons as class members and access them from your Activity by get methods.

2) Write an Interface that will have the callback methods so you know which Button is being clicked. Once you write the interface you pass it as a constructor parameter or by a set method. Something like:

```
interface QuizListener {
  void answered(Button whichButton);
}

...
[RecyclerViewAdapter.java]
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<questions> TempList, QuizListener quizListener) {
  this.context = context;
  this.list = TempList;
  this.quizListener = quizListener;
}

...

option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (quizListener != null) {
      quizListener.answered(option1);
    }
    option1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong);
  }
});
```